# Q: How to correctly include a categorial control variable in a regression model (in R)?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, interaction

I'm trying to fit a (logistic) regression model to predict the successful funding of crowdfunding ventures (0/1) based on a series of IV with different level of measurement. One of these IVs is a categorial variable that indicates the nature of the venture (like technology, media, etc.). From visually inspecting the IVs I can see that the other IVs take different values relative to the venture category.

**My question is, how do I properly incorporate the categorial variable into a regression model (using R)?**

I do realize I could simply add the categorial variable with all the other IVs like this:

```
glm(success ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3 + ... + ventureCategory +, data=data, family="binomial")
```

From what I understand this would only return the overall influence of the venture categories on successful funding, but not the potential interaction between venture category and IV1 to IVn.

If I was to include interactions, how would I know which interactions to add?
And if I assume the venture category to be influential on all the IVs do I include separate interactions for every IV with the ventureCategory like this

```
glm(success ~ IV1 + Iv1:ventureCategory + IV2 + Iv2:ventureCategory + ... + ventureCategory, data=data, family="binomial")
```

It seems that model quickly becomes quiet messy and I got something mixed up here.

Finally, I read two studies, who include this exact variable differently.
Here is a link to one of them: https://balsa.man.poznan.pl/indico/getFile.py/access?contribId=5&resId=0&materialId=paper&confId=44

Their model simply states they controled for categories (see table p.12) without providing any coefficients or p values. I read this in other papers too, but do not understand how the control variable actually contributes to the model in this case.

I also read through some of the threads here, but couldn't find anything that really helped me understand the underlying rationale.

Update: I have 5 IV in total, excluding the categorial one.

Best

Comment: How many independent variables in total do you have?

Comment: Please register & merge your accounts (you can find out how on the **My Account** section of our [help]). Then you will be able to edit your own Q.

Comment: Very often when someone reports having "controlled" for a variable (like categories) in a regression, they mean that it was included as a predictor variable as a main effect. They often don't also include interactions. If you want to examine interactions you have the right way to include them (you will have 6 predictors including venture categories, plus 5 interactions) but make sure you watch out for typing errors. In your code you write `IV1` for the main effect, but `Iv1` in the interaction terms. R is case-sensitive.

Comment: The part of your post that stands out is "how would I know which interactions to add?"  You'll want to study the way other researchers select such effects to test.  They may do so based on theory/knowledge/prior evidence/hunches, or they may do so using atheoretical, opportunistic, shotgun methods such as random forests, CHAID, CART, etc.